# Available colors in Dialog

Tags: shell, dialog

In `dialog` command, we can use a `.dialogrc` file to define the dialogs styles. By default it uses the 8 terminal colors, I would like to know if I can use more than 8, like dark green and how do I define it in the configuration file.

Comment: dialog's rc-files have foreground/background/highlight for each color combination.  "highlight" is the same as "bold", which some people interpret as *bright* colors.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, Hmm I see, so `screen_color = (WHITE,GREEN,ON)` means bright green right? While `screen_color = (WHITE,GREEN,OFF)` means dark green. Here I have all these options: `Attribute  -  (foreground,background,highlight?,underline?,reverse?)`

Comment: sure - see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/7949bc77b9e3037b99ca2c0ec53db5df9a7afd60/rc.c#L254).